# How can i change dynamically button variable name in a loop with java

Tags: loops, variables, button, javafx, dynamic

i want to create multiple buttons varibales with different names in a lopp with java, what can i do to get this code automatically?

```
GridPane button_grid = new GridPane();
         Button sound_button = new Button("Lire livre N°");
         Button sound_button2 = new Button("Lire livre N°1");
         Button sound_button3 = new Button("Lire livre N°2");
         Button sound_button4 = new Button("Lire livre N°3");
         Button sound_button5 = new Button("Lire livre N°4");
         Button sound_button6 = new Button("Lire livre N°5");
         Button sound_button7 = new Button("Lire livre N°6");
         Button sound_button8 = new Button("Lire livre N°7");
         Button sound_button9 = new Button("Lire livre N°8");
         Button sound_button10 = new Button("Lire livre N°9");
button_grid.add(sound_button, 1,1);
        button_grid.add(sound_button2, 2,1);
        button_grid.add(sound_button3, 3,1);
        button_grid.add(sound_button4, 4,1);
        button_grid.add(sound_button5, 5,1);
        button_grid.add(sound_button6, 6,1);
        button_grid.add(sound_button7, 7,1);
        button_grid.add(sound_button8, 8,1);
        button_grid.add(sound_button9, 9,1);
        button_grid.add(sound_button10,10,1);
```

My objective, is to insert a gridPane into a scrollPane into a VBox, this is my code

```
public class controller {

     ScrollPane scrollPane = new ScrollPane();
     GridPane button_grid = new GridPane();
     @FXML private VBox vbox;

     public void initialize() {

         Button sound_button = new Button("Lire livre N°1");
         Button sound_button2 = new Button("Lire livre N°2");


        button_grid.add(sound_button, 1,1);
        button_grid.add(sound_button, 2,1);//<================the ERROR is Here

        scrollPane.setContent(button_grid);
        scrollPane.setVbarPolicy(ScrollBarPolicy.AS_NEEDED);
        scrollPane.setHbarPolicy(ScrollBarPolicy.AS_NEEDED);
        vbox.getChildren().add(scrollPane);
     }
```

Unfortunatelly i get an error with that code: Children: duplicate children added.
The only way to do this correctly is to have a different button's variables names
sound_button & sound_button2 etc... inserted into button_grid.
How can i have a different button's variable name inside a loop?

Best regards

Comment: Just write a `for` loop that creates a new button and adds it to the grid pane on each iteration. At least show your attempt to do so.

Comment: int r;
         for (r = 1; r <= 10 ; r++) {
          
         Button sound_button+r = new Button("Lire livre N°"+r);
          button_grid.add(sound_button+r, r,1);
           
         }

Comment: Put the code in the question, not in a comment. You can't dynamically change the name of a variable. It doesn't really make any sense to do so, because the variables go out of scope once you exit the loop anyway, so their names are completely unimportant. Why not just use the same variable name on each iteration of the loop? If you need access to them later (there's absolutely no reason why you should), put them in a list or array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't generate the name of a variable dynamically in this way in Java. Note that in your code, the reference variables for the button are scoped to the body of the loop anyway; since you can't access those variables outside the loop, it doesn't matter what they're called and you may as well let them all have the same name.

The "duplicate children" error you encounter in your code is because you are adding the *same button* to the grid pane multiple times. The variable you are using to reference the button is irrelevant.

All that actually matters is that you create a new button each time, and add it to the grid pane.

So this code fails, because it adds the *same button* twice:

```
GridPane buttonGrid = new GridPane();
Button soundButton ;

soundButton = new Button("Lire livre N°1");
buttonGrid.add(soundButton, 1, 1);
buttonGrid.add(soundButton, 2, 1); // adds same button: "duplicate children" error
```

And this code also fails, for the same reason, even though it uses different variables:

```
GridPane buttonGrid = new GridPane();
Button soundButton1 ;
Button soundButton2 ;

soundButton1 = new Button("Lire livre N°1");
buttonGrid.add(soundButton1, 1, 1);

soundButton2 = soundButton1 ; // second variable refers to same button
buttonGrid.add(soundButton2, 2, 1); // "duplicate children" error
```

Of course, this code succeeds, because it adds *two different buttons*:

```
GridPane buttonGrid = new GridPane();
Button soundButton1 ;
Button soundButton2 ;

soundButton1 = new Button("Lire livre N°1");
buttonGrid.add(soundButton1, 1, 1);

soundButton2 = new Button("Lire livre N°2"); // second variable refers to different button
buttonGrid.add(soundButton2, 2, 1); // succeeds
```

and this also succeed, because it also adds two different buttons, even though it uses the same variable twice:

```
GridPane buttonGrid = new GridPane();
Button soundButton ;

soundButton = new Button("Lire livre N°1");
buttonGrid.add(soundButton, 1, 1);

soundButton = new Button("Lire livre N°2"); // update variable to refer to different button
buttonGrid.add(soundButton, 2, 1); // succeeds
```

So in your long-hand, repetitive code, you could achieve this with a single variable:

```
GridPane buttonGrid = new GridPane();
Button soundButton ;

soundButton = new Button("Lire livre N°1");
buttonGrid.add(soundButton, 1, 1);

soundButton = new Button("Lire livre N°2");
buttonGrid.add(soundButton, 2, 1);

soundButton = new Button("Lire livre N°3");
buttonGrid.add(soundButton, 3, 1);

soundButton = new Button("Lire livre N°4");
buttonGrid.add(soundButton, 4, 1);

// etc. etc.
```

But of course you can also do this with a loop:

```
for (int r = 1; r <= 10; r++) {
    Button soundButton = new Button("Lire livre N°"+r);
    buttonGrid.add(soundButton, r, 1);
}
```

Here is a complete runnable example:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane.ScrollBarPolicy;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ButtonGrid extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        ScrollPane scrollPane = new ScrollPane();
        GridPane buttonGrid = new GridPane();
        VBox vbox = new VBox();

        for (int r = 1; r <= 10; r++) {
            Button soundButton = new Button("Lire livre N°" + r);
            buttonGrid.add(soundButton, 1, r);
        }

        scrollPane.setContent(buttonGrid);
        scrollPane.setVbarPolicy(ScrollBarPolicy.AS_NEEDED);
        scrollPane.setHbarPolicy(ScrollBarPolicy.AS_NEEDED);
        vbox.getChildren().add(scrollPane);

        Scene scene = new Scene(vbox);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }

}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, unfortunatelly i want to add the GridePane into a ScrollPane, with that code i get Children: duplicate children added, i explained the case up, regards

Comment: @Napster89 No, this code will not give you a "duplicate children" error. You get that error because you are adding the *same button* to the grid pane, not because you are using the *same variable*. Did you actually try the code I suggested?